# How to make Outlook recognize a whole link, not just a part of it?

Tags: vb.net, outlook, urlencode, uipath

my program in UiPath(VB.NET) sends messages with two types of link to local folder to a client.

First link is for browser and looks like "https://tpra.local/lib/КОМПАНИЯ/...". A problem is it's not recognized as a whole.
Outlook recognizes this link, makes blue and underlines it **only until first cyrrilic letter "К"**. This letter and everything after it is not recognized as a link. So when a client clicks it, he goes to "https://tpra.local/lib/", which is NOT a full path.

I tried to use WebUtility.UrlEncode, which is belived to replace cyrrilic symbols, but it replaced ALL symbols, including slashes, so Outlook does not undestand a link either.

But the link without "https" //tpra...local/lib/КОМПАНИЯ/... - works well and opens a correct directory in explorer.
I need to have both links - for explorer and for a browser - working well.
So how can i make outlook recognize whole "https" link, just like it does with other link?

Comment: When doing it via Outlooks UI you would use quotes (") around the whole part you want to be a hyperlink. Have you tried putting quotes around the url in plain text without the encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `HTMLBody` property (instead of `Body`) to a properly formatted HTML string, `<a>` tags and all.

Comment: Yeah, i did exactly that.  This letter goes to other automatic processes and contains <> symbols, so i had to replace them with &lt; and &gt.   I hope, it will work and programs wont see html blocks like <br/>...  We'll see

Comment: Sory, but it did not work out.  I can't use "is Html" flag.  The other program, which is supposed to receive this message and read blocks in <>, does not recognize info in the message. One of my links breaks: the text of a link stays at the right place, but the link path disappears. So, i'm still looking for a nice way to make Outlook recognize a whole link, even if it is a simple text mesage.

Comment: Then you must encode the Unicode characters appropriately. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding